# Destructor called twice in Shared Pointer with STL's

Tags: c++, stl, set, shared-ptr

```
// I developed my own shared pointer . I know it is not required to create 
//ur own when already there is a tested one available . But this is purely 
//for learning, understanding and thinking purpose . The below shared 
//pointer works fine in most of the cases and not causing any memory leak 
//either . But it is not working in case of STL's . Below is my shared 
//pointer .

#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class SharedPointer
{

    template<class U>
    friend class SharedPointer;

    T *p;
    int *rc;

    public:

    SharedPointer():p(NULL),rc(NULL)   {}

    template <class U>
    explicit SharedPointer(U *q)
    {
        p = static_cast<T *>(q);
        rc = new int();
        ++*rc;
    }

    ~SharedPointer()
    {
        if(rc != NULL && --*rc == 0)
        {
             delete p;
             p = NULL;
             delete rc;
             rc = NULL;
        }
    }

    T * operator -> () { return p; }
    T & operator * () { return *p; }

    template<class U>
    explicit SharedPointer(const SharedPointer<U> &q)
    {
        if(q.p)
        {
           p = static_cast<U *>(q.get());
           rc = q.rc;
           ++*rc;
        }
    }

    template<class U>
    SharedPointer<T> & operator = (const SharedPointer<U> &sp)
    {
        if(this->p != static_cast<T *>(const_cast<U *>(sp.get())))
        {
            if(p != NULL)
            {
                if(--*rc == 0)
                {
                    delete p;
                    delete rc;
                    p = NULL;
                    rc = NULL;
                }
            }
            if(sp.get())
            {
                p = static_cast<T *>(sp.get());
                rc = sp.rc;
                ++*rc;
            }
            else
            {
                p = NULL;
                rc = NULL;
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
// And now below is the usage .
class A
{
    int i;
    public:
    A(int pi):i(pi){  }
    ~A() 
    {
        cout<<"Destructor Called for "<<i<<endl;
    }
    void show()
    {
        cout<<i<<endl;
    }
    int intake()   {  return i;   }
};
struct A_Comp
{
    bool operator()(const SharedPointer<A> &lhs, const SharedPointer<A> &rhs)
    {
        return lhs->intake() < rhs->intake();
    }
};
int main()
{
    set<SharedPointer<A>,A_Comp> myset;
    A * a = new A(30);
    myset.insert(SharedPointer<A>(a));   //   Line X
    set<SharedPointer<A> >::iterator itr;
    for(itr = myset.begin(); itr != myset.end(); itr++)
    {
       (*itr)->show();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

Destructor Called for 30

4151280

Actually what exactly happening is that ,  the Line X (see comments) is getting executed , it is calling explicit SharedPointer(U *q) which is as expected but the moment this constructor finishes , the destructor of SharedPointer is getting called which is deleting that variable . Hence the second line which is coming is garbage value which could be different in different execution . My question is why the ~SharedPointer is getting called when it should be executed only just before return statement  of main function . Though the ~SharedPointer is getting called just before return of main but I am not able to figure out why it is getting called for the first time . The standard shared_ptr doesn't have this behaviour .

I am using -fpermissive option to avoid const related error .

Comment: Can you reduce that down to a [mcve]?

Comment: @R Sahu , I removed extra function . Thanks .

Comment: @manni , I used the debugger , Only the came to know the ~SharedPointer is getting called the moment SharedPointer(U *p) constructor finishes . But not able to figure out why as that object is not going to be out of scope before return statement of main .

Comment: For a shared_ptr to work you need to move the pointer-holding to an object other than the shared_ptr itself, if you have the shared_ptr own the pointer you will run into problems with copy and assignment operations where one shared_ptr (even a temporary) goes out of scope and is destroyed taking the pointer with it.

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPointer` has an implicit compiler-generated copy constructor and copy assignment operator, which perform simple member-wise copy and don't maintain reference count. It is this copy constructor that is called at `Line X` (put a breakpoint or print something in your templated constructor - you'll see that it's never called).

A template constructor is never a copy constructor, and therefore doesn't prevent implicitly-declared copy constructor. You need to add `SharedPointer(const SharedPointer&)` constructor.